# install of shindig:error in wampserver

Tags: wampserver

I want install shindig in WampServer ,i uncomment always_populate_raw_post_data' to 'On' in php.ini but not work :
Your environment does not have always_populate_raw_post_data enabled which will interfere with Shindig. Please set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to 'On' in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You have probably edited the wrong php.ini file, there are 2 ( at least )

If you want to edit the php.ini file that is used by Apache, then use the menus on the wampmanager icon that sits in the system tray, this will edit the correct file.

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> PHP.INI
```

If you want to use the PHP CLI (Command Line Interface) then edit the php.ini that lives in the `\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z\php.ini`

They both have different and unique uses.

*ADDITIONAL INFO ON CURL*

For curl to work you also need to uncomment these extensions :-

```
extension=php_curl
```

You also need these dll's libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll which are in the phpx.y.z folder to be on your path. Avoid advice to copy these files to any \windows\?? folders.

It may be easier to just create a simple windows command file that sets the path up so your php folder is on the path.

This is what I use :-

Filename = phppath.cmd

```
echo off
PATH=%PATH%;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.22
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------
php -v
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Change the php5.3.22 folder name to the version of PHP you are using.

Store this file in a folder that is already on your PATH and then you can run it from anywhere in any folder. Once it has been run PHP will be available to you by just running

```
phppath
php script.php
```

It should also be able to find libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll because they are in the php folder which is now in a folder on your PATH.

Comment: I modify the \wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z\php.ini  and the error was eliminate but another error is show Shindig requires the curl extention, see http://www.php.net/curl for more info but i uncomment  'curl.extension ' in php.ini